# Tkinter: How to make a fixed canvas size with scroll bars that resize to the window

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am attempting to create fixed-size canvas widget with scroll bars. The canvas in question could be quite large, and will almost definitely be much larger than the frame containing it. I would like to keep the canvas at its fixed size, but be able to resize the window containing it. The issue I am having is I don't know how to bind the scroll bars to the edge of the window.

I have tried both .pack and .grid. The obvious issue with .grid is that it will simply place the scroll bars next to the canvas. Unfortunately, the canvas must have a fixed size that will always be larger than the window. Whenever I .pack, the canvas appears to resize with the window, even when I explicitly disable  expand and set fill to None.

I have made set the background to black for the purpose of clearly seeing the canvas area.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class DialogueCreation(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.xbar = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.xbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.ybar = tk.Scrollbar(parent)
        self.ybar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.item_canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=5000, height=5000, xscrollcommand=self.xbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.ybar.set)
        self.item_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=FALSE, fill=None)
        self.item_canvas.configure(background='black')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    DialogueCreation(root)
    root.title("Editor")
    root.mainloop()
```

The canvas is a massive 5000x5000, so I should definitely be able to scroll when the window is small. I want the scrollbars to remain flush with the edges of the window, without resizing my canvas. The scrollbars remain dormant no matter how large or small the window is. I'm assuming the canvas is resizing with the window, which is definitely not the desired result.

Eventually this canvas will have several images displayed on it, and the location of those images must not change on the canvas. I do not believe the issue is with how I bound the scrollbars (I checked several other posts on this website to make sure), but it would not be uncharacteristic if I missed something obvious like that.

Comment: I had to add the following line to the example code to see the canvas:                                     self.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE, fill=tk.BOTH) to the end of the DialogueCreation __init__ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you want to create a fixed size canvas, I'm assuming that you mean you want the drawable area to be a fixed size, rather than have a fixed size for the viewable portion of the canvas.

To do that, you need to set the `scrollregion` attribute to the drawable area. You use the `width` and `height` attributes to set the size of the visible portion of the canvas.

Also, hooking up scrollbars is a two way street: you've got to configure the canvas to update the scrollbars, and configure the scrollbars to scroll the canvas.

**Note**: you made `DialogCreation` a `Frame`, yet you put all of the widgets directly in the parent. That's very unusual, and not the best way to do it. I recommend inheriting from `Frame` like you do, but then all of the widgets should go in `self` rather than parent.

When you do it this way, you need to make sure you call `pack` on the instance of `DialogCreation`, eg:

```
dr = DialogueCreation(root)
dr.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

### Using pack

With `pack`, you should set the `expand` option to `True` if you want the visible portion to grow or shrink when the user resizes the window.

My personal experience is that code is easier to understand and easier to maintain if you separate widget creation from widget layout. The following code shows how I would rewrite your code using `pack`. Notice the additional lines for configuring `xbar` and `ybar`, as well as setting the `scrollregion`.

```
class DialogueCreation(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.xbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.ybar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.item_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400,
                                     xscrollcommand=self.xbar.set,
                                     yscrollcommand=self.ybar.set)

        self.xbar.configure(command=self.item_canvas.xview)
        self.ybar.configure(command=self.item_canvas.yview)

        self.item_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,4999,4999))
        self.item_canvas.configure(background='black')

        self.xbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.ybar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.item_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
```

### Using grid

> The obvious issue with .grid is that it will simply place the scroll bars next to the canvas.

I don't see that as obvious at all. `grid` has no such restriction. You can put the scrollbar anywhere you want.

The important thing to remember with `grid` is that rows and columns do not automatically grow or shrink when the window as a whole changes size. You have to explicitly tell tkinter which rows and columns to grow and shrink.

To achieve the same effect as with using `pack`, you need to configure row zero, column zero to be given all extra space. You do that by giving them a `weight` that is greater than zero.

To use `grid` instead of `pack`, replace the last three lines of the above example with the following six lines:

```
self.item_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.xbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
self.ybar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: The issue was the scrollregion setting. I originally had the scroll bars configured to update, but those lines must have been deleted in my frenzied code editing. The issue I was having with .grid is, without the scrollregion being set, it forced the scrollbars to be on the very edge of the canvas at all times, which was out of the bounds of the window. Thank you.

Comment: @Brandon: that's not an issue with grid. The use of grid is completely unrelated to how the scrollbars work.

Comment: I understand that, my misunderstanding was not with the function of the scrollbars. The issue was with the widget geometry. When placing the scrollbars using .grid, they were placed below and next to the canvas. Because the canvas size was fixed and the scroll region was not set, the scrollbars were not visible unless the window was expanded to the massive size of the canvas. Setting the scroll region allowed the viewable area of the canvas to resize without resizing the canvas itself, so the scrollbars were able to remain visible in the window. At least that is my understanding.